# PivotX/Y in ViewPropertyAnimation

Tags: android

```
if (savedInstanceState==null) {
        ViewTreeObserver observer = mPopupLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
        observer.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw()
            {
                mPopupLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                mPopupLayout.setScaleX(0.0f);
                mPopupLayout.setScaleY(0.0f);
                mPopupLayout.animate()
                        .setDuration(mDuration)
                        .setInterpolator(sDecelerator)
                        .scaleY(1.0f).scaleX(1.0f);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

I'm using this code, my animation starts by going from left-bottom to right-top but I want it to go from right-top to left-bottom. I checked some posts and one suggestion said to use `PivotX/Y` but I couldn't find `PivotX/Y` in `viewpropertyanimation`, how can I do this?

EDIT//
thanks for @kcoppock's answer.first i got PivotX/y from getPivotX/Y then i change x to y and y to x value valaaaa that's result. thanks

Comment: For future reference: you should always start your SO questions with an introduction to what you are doing, and what your code is supposed to do, so that readers know what the to look for in the code *before* they start reading through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With animators you actually need to set the pivot on the view itself:

```
mPopupLayout.setPivotX();
mPopupLayout.setPivotY();
```

Comment: in your experience what should i set X and Y for right-top to left-bottom ?

Comment: I'm not sure your question makes sense. This just sets the position from which the scale will start. Pivot X of 0 means the left of the view. Pivot Y of 0 means the top of the view. Play around with it a bit and you should get the hang of it.